# vimeo iframe thumbnails too small on safari browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web

on my nextjs page the thumbnail of a vimeo video is displayed at a super small size on safari, despite having set it and the measurements of the containers to 100%.

when using the react video component (for locally stored videos) it behaves fine, the issue only occurs with the iframe embeds on safari.

any idea how to fix this?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctHRj.png)
(dark grey area is the iframe's container, the black rectangle the thumbnail before the video is started. when clicking on the thumbnail the video loads into the container filling out the container how it's supposed to)

i've tried changing the iframe styling settings to display: block, all sides to 0px, and position: absolute.
but no noticable changes

Comment: You stand a much better chance of getting an answer if you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question. Your reader will be able to confirm what you assert, and they have an easy way to test their ideas.